# Deriving type of foldr (!!)

Tags: haskell, types, ghci, unification

```
foldr :: (a->b->b)->b->[a]->b
(!!)::[c]->Int->c
```

From that we get `a->b->b=[c]->Int->c`
or `a=[c],b=Int,b=c`.
We conclude that type of foldr (!!) is `Int->[[Int]]->Int`.
Is it correct?
WinGHCi tells me something different:

```
Prelude> :t foldr (!!)
foldr (!!) :: Foldable t => Int -> t [Int] -> Int
```

Comment: `foldr` has been generalized to `Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Nowadays `foldr` is more general than it used to be, so it returns a more general type. To simplify these "new" types, you can pretend that `Foldable t` isn't there if you replace every `t something` in the type with `[something]`. In this way, you lose the more general type, and get what you would expect.

Comment: Thank you @chi!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [**`foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr) indeed in the early days had the signature `(a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`, but they have *generalized* the function, such that it *not only* works with lists (where `t ~ []`), but with other `Foldable` types (like `Maybe`, `Sum`, etc. as well). But for the list case, nothing changes, the function is simply applicable to more `Foldable` types.

## Deriving the type for the "old" `foldr`

In that case we take as ingredients:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
(!!) :: [c] -> Int -> c
```

or more verbose:

```
foldr :: (a -> (b -> b)) -> (b -> ([a] -> b))
(!!) :: [c] -> (Int -> c)
```

Since `(!!)` is the parameter of the call with `foldr` as function, we know that the type of the `(!!) :: [c] -> (Int -> c)` function should match with the type of the parameter of `foldr`, so `(a -> b -> b)`. So that means:

```
  a -> (b -> b)
~ [c] -> (Int -> c)
--------------------
a ~ [c], b ~ c ~ Int
```

So we know that `a` is the same type as `[c]`, and that both `b` and `c` are actually `Int`. Therefore we know that `a ~ [Int]`.

So now the type of `foldr (!!)` is the output type of `foldr`, but specialized with what we derived, so:

```
b -> ([a] -> b)
```

which is equal to:

```
Int -> ([[Int]] -> Int)
```

or less verbose:

```
Int -> [[Int]] -> Int
```

## Deriving the type of the "*new*" `folr`

In that case we take as ingredients:

```
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
(!!) :: [c] -> Int -> c
```

and we follow the same reasoning for the first parameter of `foldr`:

```
  a -> (b -> b)
~ [c] -> (Int -> c)
--------------------
a ~ [c], b ~ c ~ Int
```

So the output type of `foldr` is:

```
Foldable t => b -> (t a -> b)
```

or specified with what we know:

```
Foldable t => Int -> t [Int] -> Int
```

Which is what `ghci` derived.

## The semantics of the function

As for the semantics, the function:

```
f = foldr (!!)
```

takes as input an `Int` (an index), and a `Foldable` of lists of `Int`s. In case of a list, it will - right-to-left - obtain the element with that index, of the most right list, and use that element as an index for the one last but one list. We keep doing that until the first list, and return the element.

For example:

```
foldr (!!) 1 [] -> 1
foldr (!!) 1 [[2, 0]] -> 0
foldr (!!) 1 [[3, 5], [2, 0]] -> 3
```

For the `t ~ Maybe` case, we will thus return the original index in case of a `Nothing`, or we will return the element at that index in case it is a `Just [1, 4, 2, 5]` (a `Just` that carries a `[Int]` object). For example:

```
foldr (!!) 1 Nothing -> 1
foldr (!!) 3 Nothing -> 3
foldr (!!) 1 (Just [1, 4, 2, 5])-> 4
foldr (!!) 3 (Just [1, 4, 2, 5])-> 5
```

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the generalized type of foldr.  
Thanks for your informative answer and clear derivations.

Answer (score 4):

As noted in the comments, in recent GHC, `foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`.  When `t ~ []`, `Foldable t => Int -> t [Int] -> Int` simplifies to `Int->[[Int]]->Int`, as you expected.

There are a couple of ways to get GHCi to print the more specific type.  One is to add the type signature that you expect, and have GHCi verify.

```
> :t foldr (!!) :: Int->[[Int]]->Int
foldr (!!) :: Int->[[Int]]->Int :: Int -> [[Int]] -> Int
```

Another is to give an explicit type for `t`, before the normal (term) arguments to `foldr`:

```
> :t foldr @[] (!!)
foldr @[] (!!) :: Int -> [[Int]] -> Int
```

This uses [TypeApplications](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#visible-type-application).  The syntax is `@` followed by the type name.